# Don't say "Your question is ready to publish!" if "This post does not meet our quality standards"

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, low-quality-posts, error-message, quality-filter

Don't say "Your question is ready to publish!" if "This post does not meet our quality standards".

[image]

---

Steps to reproduce this:

1. Go to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask (note: the issue is not specific to this Stack Exchange website)
2. Add "Is the expression “very worth” proper English, and if not, what are some alternatives?" in the title and body
3. Add "gmail" as tag
4. Click on "review your question"
5. Click on "post your question"

To be clear, I'm *not* asking for specific feedback on the question above. It is just an example that I used to demonstrate the issue I'm concerned about, which is that the "Your question is ready to publish!" message is displaying for questions that don't meet the site's quality standards. Instead of that message, the user should be told that the question isn't ready to publish because it doesn't meet quality standards.

Comment: Ha! But maybe you met the minimum requirements set by SE? Ah, I see what the problem was, the question is off-topic on webapps.

Comment: @Mari-LouA don't these requirements include the quality standards? I just used webapps for the example, same issue if posted on ell SE. The requirements don't check whether the question is on-topic.

Comment: Descriptive title (check) , decent grammar and spelling (check), there is a proper question, (check) and it's not a duplicate (check).  I don't know what criteria is, but if you have a question meeting these essential elements, it's a good step forward. If the question is off-topic then humans will close it pretty quickly.

Comment: @Mari-LouA thanks, the question is just one example to illustrate the issue  that SE says "Your question is ready to publish!" Ans "This post does not meet our quality standards" at the same time

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - We don't have the AI that can determine if a question is good or bad, so has MariLou A pointed out, the workflow checks for specific things.  As for the quality standard problem, that is obvious, the body and the title are identical.  That is the most likely reason it's not being posted.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks I'm aware of that (the quality issue comes from the length of the question details, not its repetition with the title). As stated in the comments and the question, the question is just one example to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Thanks for raising this. I agree this is confusing with the conflicting messages. I've added this to our team's list to address and will update here with more when we get to it.