# Automated question review scrolls away from a "Post doesn't meet our quality standards" error

Tags: bug, user-interface, asking-questions

This was something I found when testing a bit of low-quality content against the system.  This error:

[image]

Appeared when I clicked the "Post question" button (*not* the review), but the page scrolled back up to show this:

[image]

Instead of scrolling down a touch to show you the error.  I imagine this would be a little confusing for new users, and was confusing to me too.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Enter `This is a test title to test something` in the title and body.
2. Enter [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) as the tag.
3. Click "Review" and then "Post question".

Can we fix this please, and don't show the "Question ready to publish" notice when the quality error comes up.

Comment: Related [Don't say “Your question is ready to publish!” if “This post does not meet our quality standards”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348887/289691) , Duplicate?

Comment: @Rubén That's a good point!  Thanks for finding it, I've closed it as a duplicate.