# A question having a single word in the body passed the quality filter (spoiler: the body contains HTML entities)

Tags: feature-request, bug, asking-questions, quality-filter

Despite that the question is off-topic in Web Applications, this question having a single visible word on the body was able to be posted by a new contributor

[image]

Body markdown

```
Title&#173;&#8203;&#173;&#8203;&#173;&#8203;&#173;&#8203;&#173;&#8203;&#173;&#8203;&#173;&#8203;&#173;&#8203;&#173;&#8203;&#173;&#8203;&#173;&#8203;&#173;&#8203;&#173;&#8203;&#173;&#8203;&#173;&#8203;&#173;&#8203;
```

---

When I tried to do the same (without using HTML entities or any other trick), after clicking on the *Review your question* button, the Ask page displayed "Your question is ready to publish!"

[image]

When I click the Post your question button, it showed the "Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 5."

[image]

No "This post doesn't meet our quality standards" warning was shown

**Feature request:** Make the quality filter able to review the rendered question content
**Bug:** The quality standards pop-up alert was not shown

Related

- [Should "Title Says It All" questions be edited or closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119410/289691)
- [Don't say "Your question is ready to publish!" if "This post does not meet our quality standards"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348887/289691)
- [(empty question)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359283/289691)