# ‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​It's possible to create empty content fields - particularly question titles and bodies - on sites

Tags: bug, posts

‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​Prior to an edit, this question was posted with no content in it, both in the title and the question body.

[image: Screenshot of the current post before it was edited. The Meta banner is visible as is the score and other elements of the page but the title space and post body are completely empty of text, showing only the post notice banner stating that the post was migrated from Meta Stack Overflow]

The explanation to reproduce is provided in [Temani Afif's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359284/284336).

Since this was discovered, similar text fields around the site have been found to have similar issues and they are outlined in the answers below.

### Note from Catija:

While we appreciate all the effort y'all have gone to to test and find places this is possible, we'd like this question to be understandable so that seeing it doesn't cause confusion. Feel free to add additional information [to this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380594/208518) but please leave the question itself as-is. Also, while y'all are free to continue to seek out these issues, we hope that you would all refrain from actually abusing this feature.

Comment: We can even submit empty questions. This need to be fixed

Comment: This was incredibly hard to get to; nothing is clickable from the Tagged Questions page. Why would you do this?!

Comment: @Scratte ah, links! yes a good idea to fill the needed characters

Comment: Duplicate: [Can we create invisible things?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95152/7103).

Comment: I still can't stop laughing...  You know how *BAD* this looks in the followed posts menu??

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404302/are-whitespace-only-display-names-allowed

Comment: @Ollie Honestly... not really worse than it looks in the questions list. I expected something more horrifying :)

Comment: Chat oneboxen of this post are also not clickable... which is fun cause I thew this into a chatroom to keep an eye on it...

Comment: @Zoethe1337Princess Of course: [question title does not appear and I can not access this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359301/289905)…

Comment: Doesn’t Stack Exchange use a bug tracker internally with questions being automatically added as soon as they get the [tag:status-review] tag? I’m wondering what _this_ question looks like in the bug tracker.

Comment: Staff, while you're at it, please have a look at my [similar request for usernames](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326747/295232).

Comment: Related: [Zero-width non-joiner allows unclickable titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44011/209901)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' another one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10519/386331 ... seems like I ressurected a very very old bug after 10 years

Comment: So this is like Winter Bash, but instead of hunting for hats we are hunting for places we can post empty stuff.

Comment: Not really no. Its meta being meta and testing things to destruction, like infinite monkeys with infinite bolts of silk recreating the works of Christo :D

Comment: Proposed solution: replace isEmpty() check with isBlank()

Comment: Given the answers, I was tempted to add the [tag:fun] tag... Apparently we're all still in Winter Bash mode :)

Comment: I'm laughing at the "Needs details or clarity" close vote here... how could you make the problem any clearer?

Comment: @AdamLear Be careful what you expect when it comes to horrifying things or your users may exceed expectations.

Comment: @ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ why, just why do you have to do this?

Comment: @10Repsaysgetvaccinated Sorry ;)

Comment: @ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ btw your username renders as hexagons with question marks in them when I copy pasted it into vim.

Comment: @10Repsaysgetvaccinated Tinkeringbell thoroughly chastised me and changed my username back.  It's all good now ;)

Comment: @10Repsaysgetvaccinated No, it's our goal to find bugs and report them so Stack Exchange *isn't* ruined.  And possibly have a little fun in the process.

Comment: Ok, it's not possible :(. Tags are a little stricter than question bodies because you have to create a tag before using it.

Comment: I have enough rep on Stack Overflow, but that would be abusing it, so I don't really want to.

Comment: Note – since it may get a bit lost among the other answers below, [there's an official response regarding this issue here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379734/335251).

Comment: ‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386228/1319485

Answer (score 54):

As we can *not* see, I was able to submit an empty question.

To reproduce it:

1. Submit a question with a content
2. Right after the submission, edit the question to remove everything and include invisible zero-width spaces.

Edit the below snippet to be able to see the spaces (they will show as red dots if you are using Chrome)

```html
‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​
```

---

The system didn't allow me to submit the question initially due to the quality check but there was no quality check after edits.

---

We can, by the way, submit empty answers without the need of an edit after (see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359285/598066)).

Comment: I can see this is going to be a real pain to stop people doing this, but also I suspect that it's going to be unlikely be abused. If anything, if someone does this with malicious intent they'll likely just going to get stern words from the mods. Though, I won't lie, the whole thing is really amusing. It would be even better if we'd all lumped in to post "blank" comments and answers. ;)

Comment: @Larnu and using blank usernames ;)

Comment: That is the stuff of nightmares.

Comment: Don't focus too much on visibility. Although the content isn't visible, it's *clearly* visible that (on the main sites) this would be deliberate malpractice, making it not different than any other malpractice, which community moderation is perfectly capable of dealing with.

Comment: @GertArnold why waiting for moderation intervention when we can prevent this from happening? Few more tests on the content should do it.

Comment: _“if you are using Chrome”_ — Works in Firefox, too, at least using Nightly 86.0a1.

Comment: It's not a real pain to stop people doing this @Larnu `alter table Posts add constraint ChkPostBodyLength check (datalength(body) > 100);` (repeat for all fields with user input text).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards a zero width unicode character has a value of `2` for datalength, so 50 of them, and done. But that would also force users to post comments that are 50 characters long. That is far from desired.

Comment: The length could be different for different fields @Larnu, but you're right about the spaces having a length. You'd have to replace them first before performing the length which would make longer strings (i.e. posts) a real pain at scale.

Comment: Stripping leading/trailing spaces (including zws, zwj, etc) was routinely done on submission for years, @ben. It led to some other obscure bugs, so I'm guessing someone fixed them by moving the check without considering the implications.

Comment: LOL, this is so funny.

Answer (score 30):

Oh boy:

[image]

We can use it to raise empty custom flags.  Empty tag wikis, too.

Comment: Please don't, though.

Comment: The stackexchange team must be hating me .. I opened the pandora's box ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif The Stack Exchange community is loving you, if the upvotes are anything to tell by ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif and that box is apparently full of emptyness.

Comment: @TemaniAfif But the last thing left in the box, is hope.

Answer (score 23):

I can also use this method to screw up my "About Me" section, e.g., remove the text "Your about me is currently blank", and the "Apparently this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them" that y'all see:

[image]

Go take a look in [my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/798831/ollie?tab=profile).

Comment: [Rep for Nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cruXb.png)

Comment: @rgettman [badges for nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCBAK.png)

Comment: I'd say that *this* is by-design. Users should be able to have an empty "About Me" section, if they like.

Comment: @CodyGray They can, but empty profiles *always* show the "Apparently, this user preferred to shroud themselves in a veil of mystery" or the like.

Comment: Yeah, but what if I don't want that silliness? Seems reasonable to allow its removal. What I'm saying is, there shouldn't be a content requirement for profile pages like there needs to be for posts.

Comment: @CodyGray By all means go ahead and make an FR, but I'm just posting the bug according to the current settings.

Comment: What I'm saying is, I disagree that this is a bug.

Comment: Answer outdated, showing old avatar and also they now simply don't show the About Me section at all when there's no content.

Answer (score 21):

Empty bounty summary:

[image]

See [Where I started the bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox). (Now awarded)

Comment: and an empty duplicate banner: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359301/386331

Answer (score 21):

Thanks to @ppwater, the [empty](/questions/tagged/empty) tag now has an empty excerpt and wiki. See the [tag info page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/empty/info).

Comment: not as empty as it should be. I made it even more empty ;) [let's wait for peer approval]

Comment: This is nothing new. If you initially propose them as suggested edits and they get rejected, they'll be blank anyway.

Comment: The tag no long exists, making the link to the tag info page dead.

Comment: @bobble is correct, answer has no value now. :-(

Comment: It's function is to share the fun we all had with this bug report ...

Answer (score 16):

There's no clickable area to this post from the 10k tools' Delete Votes page (there's an answer here with a pending delete vote).

[image: Unclickable delete vote entry]

Even on posts I'm unable to vote to delete/undelete, I can still click the link to hop to that post from this entry.

Not super unique (I mean, we already know the title is unclickable) but I see other answers documenting places where this affects accessibility and figured I would add this to the list.

Answer (score 14):

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's another empty answer, but this time it's with a 1x1 transparent image.

Comment: I'm not sure how we would prevent transparent images.

Comment: Oh, this one is awesome ;)  Please take my upvote.

Comment: @Catija not sure if this helps but in python it is possible using opencv.

Comment: Preventing it is simple. Flag it, let a mod take a look, and suspend the user :D

Answer (score 13):

[image: 4]

I don't think I need any further explanations. I can create an empty room name using the ‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​ symbol.

Answer (score 12):

Empty suggested edit summary. (I edited Ollie's answer) [approved edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76611)
[image]

Edit view:

[image]

Comment: Suggested no longer, as I approved it.

Answer (score 10):

[Empty reject reason](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28021067):

> [image]

[Empty custom close reason](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65543898):

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxnvS.png

Answer (score 9):

It turns out I can have zero-width characters in my password, although I also need to add one letter and one number.

Comment: Best password ever.

Comment: In this case I don't think it's a problem, as it won't be displayed anywhere. If you want to make your password difficult to type, that's up to you.

Comment: Why did you deface your username?  Now it's impossible to find anything of yours!  Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76648, there's already a post that did that.

Answer (score 9):

### Summary of locations where this issue occurs, posted as answers

Want to contribute? Great! But please read the notes at the bottom of this post first.

| Summary | Status |
| --- | --- |
| [Empty display name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359343) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [Empty question](/a/359284) | [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) |
| [Empty "About me"](/a/359289) |  |
| [Empty custom flag](/a/359291) |  |
| [Empty chat message](/a/359293) |  |
| [Empty (suggested) edit summary](/a/359296) |  |
| [Empty bounty summary](/a/359297) |  |
| [Empty tag excerpt and wiki](/a/359309) |  |
| [Empty suggested edit rejection reason](/a/359312) |  |
| [Empty chat room name](/a/359317) |  |
| [Empty chat room tag](/a/359319) |  |
| [No clickable area when empty post is found via a tag search](/a/359321) |  |
| [Empty "other off-topic" close reason](/a/359328) |  |
| [No clickable area in 10k tools' "Delete Votes" page](/a/359338) |  |
| [Empty password](/a/359341) |  |
| [Empty site proposal name on Area 51](/a/359343) |  |
| [Alternative method to publish such empty posts](/a/359771) |  |
| [Empty answer using a 1x1 transparent pixel](/a/359819) |  |
| [Inconsistent display of the empty character in SEDE queries](/a/360278) |  |
| [No clickable area in followed posts list](/posts/comments/1199326) |  |
| [Empty "Achievements" dropdown dialog](/posts/comments/1199336) |  |
| [Empty badges](/posts/comments/1199346) |  |
| [No clickable area in chat onebox](/posts/comments/1199379) |  |
| [Empty duplicate banner](/posts/comments/1199418) |  |
| [Empty comment](/posts/comments/1269480) |  |

#### Notes

- Anybody is welcome to contribute to this post; it's a Community wiki after all.
- Sorting order: [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) > [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) > [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) >  [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) > [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) > [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) > no status tag.
- Comments can be used to discuss the structure of this post, e.g. whether the sort order above makes sense or needs to be improved.

#### Credits

Essentially copied the format from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380354/208518).

Comment: I created this answer as a placeholder, and will be filling it up early next week (lot on my plate this week). In case folks wanna start contributing, though, have at it! ^_^

Comment: Some issues have been mentioned only in the comments. These are what I could find: [empty comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1269480), [no clickable area in followed posts list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1199326), [broken chat oneboxes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1199379), and (apparently) [empty duplicate banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1199418).

Comment: Prolly ok to add to the main post, @TheAmplitwist . Also, thanks for filling that table in ^_^

Comment: Sure, I'll do that. Happy to help :)

Comment: I would say that the empty duplicate banner is not a real issue here, since that's just because the post title is empty cc@TheAmplitwist

Comment: @Luuklag Perhaps that reasoning is also applicable to the "no clickable area" issues, since they, too, only occur because of the empty post title/body. Sure, they can be removed from this list if it's clear that they don't need to be tracked.

Comment: Empty is not the same as invisible. For instance, invisible characters, even zero-width, can still (blindly) be selected by Shift + arrow key right (at least in edit views). And copied. If not zero-width it might take up space when rendered. Is this problem about using invisible characters?

Answer (score 8):

‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​What interests me is that *no matter **where*** I put the magic dots, they don't render. Search engine, [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29), [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B), [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE), [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs), etc. None of them rendered the actual dots.

Also, it's not possible to put your profile name as these characters. This is what happens when you try:

[image: Trying it out]

That doesn't mean answers and questions should work the same way, though.

Lastly, this:

[image: Bruh https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bruh#Noun_2]

Why do you have to do this to me?

Also, I've tried this [on Codidact](https://meta.codidact.com/posts/280336).

Comment: Truly, it is diabolical.  Also hilarious.

Comment: they *render* as zero-width space ;) In the HTML/CSS world, it's useful.

Comment: some related posts where I used such magic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62322234/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/57896638/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/64608352/8620333)

Answer (score 8):

People are vandalising their questions into "*no title, no body*" questions. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65859347/revisions) is an example (see [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65859347/3)).

This is the 2nd or 3rd time I am seeing this happen in *the wild*...

---

People *testing it out* in [answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/1313879):

[image]

Comment: flag such behavior .. vandalism isn't something new. I'd prefer empty content rather than *bad* words

Comment: Agree with @Temani - that's just one way to vandalize, they can also edit it into "plz delete" over 100 lines, seen it done countless times. High rep users can rollback, and if it goes on moderator can suspend the problematic user and/or lock the post.

Comment: If you see this then flag. It's no different from normal vandalism.

Comment: Another test : https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361810/598066

Answer (score 8):

I posted here earlier that the issue had been fixed, but it's reported that the issue still persisted. I just moved it back to status-review.

**Update 7/15/2022:**
The previous fix was grouping consecutive zero width characters into a single one when we validate the post length, which fixed the issue on my machine If I used the steps listed here to reproduce it.

We looked at this issue again and decided to remove all zero width characters when validating length. This change only affects length validation, and it doesn't actually remove the characters.

Comment: not for me, I was able to submit an empty answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379735/386331

Comment: If you will elaborate what exactly has been fixed, maybe we can point out what's still missing? (e.g. if you only fixed the bug allowing to submit empty questions, there's still a bug when posting empty answers.)

Comment: We added a check to remove all zero width spaces and zero width non joiners when we validate question and answer body. I wasn't able to submit an empty answer just now. But I'll change this back to status review.

Comment: Well probably the trick is using something else, @TemaniAfif can you please elaborate how exactly you were able to post empty answer yesterday? What characters were used?

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar check the most upvoted answer. I already detailed how to create empty question/answer

Comment: @ShiyaoLi the bug report is about many places where users can submit empty content, you fixed only empty posts. I don't think it is [tag:status-completed], unless you prefer to have each as a separate bug report?

Comment: I created [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380594/208518) to start keeping track of all the places where this issue is occurring, so we can better track it, @ShadowTheKidWizard — feel free to start filling it up ;)

Answer (score 7):

As relaxed as chatroom tags already were, we can also have empty tag identifiers.

[image: Example of an empty chatroom tag]

The same can't be said about tags created through the `[tag:...]` format.

Answer (score 6):

You can post empty chat messages with this trick:

[image]

Comment: yes was going to edit my answer to include it too ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif too late ;)

Answer (score 5):

> |||[image]|||

The `|` bars are for indicating the edges of the image.

Empty "other off-topic close reason" indeed.

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

One can use Unicode [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) to produce an almost empty display name.

[image]

Try it yourself:

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  textarea.focus();
  textarea.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  textarea.blur();
});
```

```html
Select all and copy in the textarea below or 
press the Copy button to get an almost empty 
display name you can set. <br>
<textarea readonly>̣̣̣</textarea> <br>
<button>Copy</button>
```

Comment: It's Unicode combining characters, right?

Comment: @̣̣̣ Yes. I see you've tried it.

Comment: This has been fixed - display names cannot consist entirely of malformed combining characters or other similarly invisible characters. They must contain at least one visible character (in addition to the other rules that already existed).

Comment: @KylePollard how can you tell 1) when combining characters are malformed?, 2) whether a character is visible or not?

Comment: For visibility, we checks each [`Rune`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.rune?view=net-6.0) of the string for it's [`UnicodeCategory`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.unicodecategory?view=net-6.0). A display name must contain at least one rune having the category `Letter`, `Number`, `Punctuation`, or `Symbol` categories. (eg. `ModifierLetter` or `OtherPunctuation`)

Comment: A malformed combining character would be one that's not combined with another character. For example, you can add the combining character representing an acute accent`◌́` (U+0301) with `e` (U+0065) to get `é` (U+0065 U+0301), like in `Pokémon`. Note that this is a different than the single character than `é` (U+00E9). If you were to put just the combining character ` ◌́ ` (U+0301) on it's own, it would be malformed because it's not combined. Some programs add `◌` (U+25CC) to represent that there should have been a character, but others just reject it outright.

Answer (score 5):

There is also another method I found that will do all the things posted so far (credit to a vandal).  The characters are in the below snippet:

```
ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤIt stops here.  Copy/paste the chars <-- from "It".
```

They are Korean Unicode characters - a Hangul filler (U+3164).

Comment: "I'm still trying to find out what they are." It appears to be Korean Unicode, a Hangul filler (U+3164).

Comment: Yes, there are several nonprintable Unicode characters, e.g. `⠀` (U+2800), the blank Braille character. I don’t think it’s necessary to add another answer for each one of them. It doesn’t even matter if Stack Exchange fixes the ZWSP bug for all nonprintables or just for U+200B, as `⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁⠁` would be an equally low-quality post and should not be accepted anyway.

Answer (score 4):

It works on the Area 51 Stack Exchange site:

[image]
‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​

It doesn't work on example questions as far as I know.

Comment: Yes I know Area51.SE uses old code.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike on the main questions feed, there is no clickable area I can find for this question on a tag search: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/empty

[image: Screenshot of question]

Comment: How about "Edited 2 mins ago by OrangeDog"...

Comment: it's only available on my profile or the active tab

Comment: @Luuklag there is no such text

Comment: @TemaniAfif it's also clickable in the "Linked" section from other questions

Comment: @OrangeDog that's because you sort on Newest, and not on Active

Comment: You can access with <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: @ppwater enjoying the limited markdown in comments? :D

Comment: @10Repsaysgetvaccinated that's not markdown :P

Comment: ... this is too funny

Answer (score 2):

I can make a SEDE query with this now: `SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Body='%‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​%';`

I am using Chrome, but it does not appear as a red dot in here

But in SEDE:
[image: not really bugged]

But, if I visit its saved link:
[image: bugg]