# The Empty tag is a meaningless void of meta

Tags: discussion, tags

I just came across  [empty](/questions/tagged/empty). It's a classic meta tag, bereft of meaning.

I'd like to consign it to the void, and proper oblivion, but I wonder if anyone finds meaning in emptiness. So... any reasons to keep what feels like a classic meta tag?

Comment: Related to [The tag wiki excerpt is displayed at the top of the page for the tag, as well as when hovering over the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359283/223467)?

Comment: That brought it to my attention :D

Comment: If you propose tags via a suggested edit and that edit gets rejected then they start blank so having blank tag descriptions doesn't seem like a newly discovered thing.

Comment: @RobertLongson but there is the default text that shows to tell that there is nothing yet and you add something

Comment: @RobertLongson the tag was already long existing. I added it to that question. Some users edited the tag wiki and excerpt to also be completely blank, using the same trick as was used with that question.

Comment: I assume there was more than one question with the tag when you opened this discussion... Seems some users have been busy acting before a consensus was reached. :-(

Comment: There were 8. I did 2 which were either dupe, or suffered from link rot. Rest I have no idea about :D

Comment: And then there were none. Though, I suppose [[tag:empty]] having no questions might be fitting?